# I am trying to print out the strings with their respective scores

Tags: python

I have taken two lists of strings and taken the cartesian product of the two lists and produce a score (fuzzy match). However, I can only get the score of each pair of strings to return when I want the pair of strings to print alongside the score. Any ideas?

```
#convert the datadrame into  a list
my_list1 = address['Street'].tolist()
my_list2 = address['Street'].tolist()
```

I won't show the function that does the fuzzy matching comparison for sake of keeping the question clean, but I will show the code where I call in the function and I will show the output

```
#Assign your list1
Test_addrs = my_list1
#Assign your List2 and build the nested loop
target_addr = my_list2
for addr in Test_addrs:
    for target in target_addr:
        distance = string_match(target, addr, ratio_calc = True)
        #print the scores
        print(distance)

Output:
100.0
35.9
41.18
```

How can I get the pair of strings to print along side these scores?

Comment: `print(target, addr, distance)`?

Comment: wow. I guess I thought this was going to print out the two lists before taking the product of the two strings. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (f'Address: {addr}, Target: {target}, Distance: {distance}')
```

For more information on how to use f string literals in Python3.6 and above:
https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/